# Ajax.BeginForm Causes Postback - Validation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to get my model validated in the client side (before postback), but it doesn't seem to work. Here's a piece of my code:

View:

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content( "~/scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content( "~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content( "~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>       
}

@using(Ajax.BeginForm("AddPhase", new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId = "newPhaseSeparator",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter
})) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div id="newPhase">
        <input type="text" id="phaseName" name="name" /> 
        <button id="btnAddPhase">Ok</button>
    </div>
}
```

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In the `AddPhase` action, ModelState.IsValid is false, which means annotations are indeed working. Is there a way to perform model validation from client-side and therefore avoid postback?

Comment: Could you show your controller action to which you are submitting this form? Also is there an `id="newPhaseSeparator"` element in your DOM? Also in your AjaxOptions you seem to be using `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter` which obviously will duplicate the error summaries returned by the server which seems in contradiction with what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Hi Darin, thanks for the quick response. I don't think the controller's action is relevant in this case because I'm trying to avoid a postback. But as I mentioned in my post, ModelState.IsValid is false. Regarding your other questions, yes there is a newPhaseSeparator element. Error summaries are indeed duplicating, but what I'm trying to achieve is avoid checking model's state in my controller's action.

Answer (score 2):

If you want unobtrusive javascript validation to work you're gonna have to use strongly typed helpers to generate your input field instead of hardcoding it as you did:

```
<div id="newPhase">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    <button id="btnAddPhase">Ok</button>
</div>
```

this obviously assumes thet your view is strongly typed to the model shown in your question, which seems normal, and in addition to that you will now notice the corresponding HTML5 data-* attributes on the input field when you analyze your generated markup. Those attributes were not present when you hardcoded your input field (`<input type="text" id="phaseName" name="name" />`) and the unobtrusive validation scripts do not have any effect.

If you are not following good practices and your view is not strongly typed to the view model you could still use the weakly typed version (totally not recommended):

```
@Html.TextBox("Name")
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. And is there a way to check if the model is valid prior to the form being submitted using jquery?

Comment: Yes, you could use the jquery unobtrusive validation scripts based on the jquery.validate plugin.

Comment: And does jquery unobtrusive validation require strongly typed helpers? In this case, `@using(Ajax.BeginForm` is rendered into an html form with `id="form5"`. I tried adding this `$("#form5").submit(function (e){ alert($(this).valid()); });` and it's always true even when the model is not valid..

Comment: No it doesn't require strongly typed helpers. You could also use weakly typed helpers even if they are not recommended. What you need for this to work is to reference the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts to your view (in that order). You also need to decorate your view model properties with the corresponding data annotations for validation (such as the `[Required]` attribute).

Comment: Still no luck.. I'm not against of using a partial view for this matter, but I'm not sure how to achieve this. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: I have two models: Project and Phase. A project can have N phases. I want to be able to create a new Phase from the Project's detail view. I created a partial view `_PhaseCreate.cshtml` and in my Details.cshtml I added `@{Html.RenderPartial("_PhaseCreate", new Models.Phase());}`. This works fine. But I also need to add in my partial view, the Id of the Job being viewed. How can I also pass this parameter to my partial view?

Comment: What does this has to do with your original question about validation?

Comment: Nothing. I'm looking for other alternatives because validating using unobtrusive jquery hasn't worked

Comment: You probably did something wrong. Hard to tell without showing us your code allowing to reproduce the error.

Comment: It's the same code as shown in my main post. I just changed `<input type="text" id="phaseName" name="name" />` for `@Html.TextBox("Name")             @Html.ValidationMessage("Name")`

Comment: Yeah great but what I was asking is a full example allowing to reproduce the problem you are describing. Showing some Html.TextBoxFor snippet from your view is not enough. Show your full _Layout, View, Controller and Action. Ideally remove all noise from crap like data access and EF, simply hardcode the values so that we don't have to setup databases, models and stuff just to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because you've misspelled the name of `<input>` tag:

```
<input type="text" id="phaseName" name="name" />
```

that should be `Name` just as your property name in the model, not `name` :

```
<input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="This field is required" id="phaseName" name="Name" />
```

And for achieving that kind of validation, you should install the `Jquery Validation` nuget package.

Then, ensure that unobtrusive validation is enabled in your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

and finally, add the following scripts to your main layout (or register them by bundles):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Amin. I changed the name in the html element but still doesn't work. Scripts are there and unobtrusive validations is enabled

Comment: @Gonzalo - I've updated my answer. you should add those two attribs to your `<input>` tag

Comment: Thanks Amin, that works! But that isn't using the annotations in my model, which is what I'm trying to accomplish. For example, if I added [StringLength], I would have to manually add the attribute to my input tag

Comment: @Gonzalo - Indeed it would not work as you like! Because you're hard-coding the input element. If you want it bounded to your view, you should use `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)` instead of `<input type="text" ... />`. That will automatically put all your annotations in the element.